# handling ids using 1 image button

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <div id="wb_Image1" style="position:absolute;left:861px;top:35px;width:30px;height:30px;z-index:12;">
 <?php 
 echo "<a href=\"institutedetaildisplay.php?id=$row['id']\"> <img src="images/img0012.png" id="Image1" alt="" title="Edit" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>"; 
 ?>
 </div>
```

Getting the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\sdbms\institutedetaildisplay.php

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: your quotes within your echo string are not escaped properly.

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP syntax rules: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: yea i do need to learn a lot. And with each one of your help it takes me a step forward in my learning. Thanks for the links. I will surely dig into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either escape all double quotes as shown in answer given by @Charles or you might consider concatenating the variables into the string like this:

```
echo '<a href="institutedetaildisplay.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"> <img src="images/img0012.png" id="Image1" alt="" title="Edit" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>';
```

Note that I am also using single quotes here to delimit the string so you don't have to escape all the double quotes within.  To me this is much easier to read, as you can make out the variable within the string at a glance.

Your main takeaway from this question however should be to understand difference in usage between `'` and `"` quotes for strings.  There are appropriate times for each.  I oftentimes find myself mixing usage within a section of code depending on what makes the code more readable.

For example, when echoing out HTML like this, I almost always use single quotes, as I don't want to escape all the double quotes in the HTML element properties.  However when defining SQL strings, I almost always use double quotes, so I don't need to escape single quotes around string values in the query.  I tend to minimize the number of quotation escapes I need to make and also tend to concatenate variables or use `{$variable}` notation (only when using double quotes) to make strings more readable.

Also as noted by @hutchbat below single quotes should perhaps be used as your default delimiter, as it is marginally faster for PHP to process that double quotes (though this might be seen as a micro-optimization).

Comment: @hutchbat True as the parser does not need to interpret the content of the string for possible variable substitution.  I pretty much always use single quotes as my default string delimiter (i.e. if there are no variable insertions to be considered).

Comment: @MikeBrant, that is a great information. +1. What about using php echo as heredoc. Any disadvantages?

Comment: will surely keep the tricks and basics in my mind :)

@mike ..thank you for the tips and also for tutoring me on the mistakes I made. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @fortune herdoc and nowdoc syntax also have their usage.  Typically I like to use these for longer sections of content or more complex SQL queries that can be made more readable by using this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

All quotes within the echo should be escaped or you need to wrap your echo in `'`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wb_Image1" style="position:absolute;left:861px;top:35px;width:30px;height:30px;z-index:12;">
 <?php 
 echo "<a href=\"institutedetaildisplay.php?id=$row['id']\"> <img src=\"images/img0012.png\" id=\"Image1\" alt=\"\" title=\"Edit\" style=\"width:30px;height:30px;\"></a>"; 
 ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output using [echo](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.echo.php):

```
<div id="wb_Image1" style="position:absolute;left:861px;top:35px;width:30px;height:30px;z-index:12;">
<?php 
echo <<<END
  <a href="institutedetaildisplay.php?id={$row['id']}"> <img src="images/img0012.png" id="Image1" alt="" title="Edit" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>
END;
?>
</div>
```